# Problems installing e2fsprogs with apk on Alpine Linux

Tags: linux, installation, raspberry-pi, packages

I'm trying to install the package e2fsprogs with apk in Alpine Linux running on a raspberry pi and I get this message:

```
$ apk add e2fsprogs
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  e2fsprogs (missing):
    required by: world[e2fsprogs]
```

But [the repository is available](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.3/main/armhf/e2fsprogs).

I tried other repositories (testing and community) with no success. Is there something I'm missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm seeing the same thing, that package is missing from the v3.4 tree, but exists in the "edge" version. If you look at the repository browser, you see that for armhf it doesn't exist for v3.4, only 3.3 and edge.

I filed a bug for it: http://bugs.alpinelinux.org/issues/5696

If you want a quick fix, you can either downgrade to v3.3 or upgrade to edge version (by switching repository in /etc/apk/repositories)

I seemed to be able to install the edge version of e2fsprogs only, without upgrading every package in the system.